# SML: non-constructor applied to argument in pattern @

Tags: sml, smlnj

Why I can't do the following and what are the ways to do it?

```
datatype boolexp = zero
                 | one 
                 | compl of boolexp;

 fun convert (#"1"::nil) = one
   | convert (#"0"::nil) = zero
   | convert (#"-":: #"(" :: xs @ [#")"]) = compl (convert xs)
```

It gives me the errors:

```
non-constructor applied to argument in pattern: @
unbound variable or constructor: xs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the last case of `convert`.

`@` is a function and not a value constructor (like `::` and `nil`), so you cannot pattern-match on it. There is no way to pattern-match on the last element of a general list.

To accomplish what you're trying to do, you can either:

- Pattern-match the beginning out, i.e. `#"-":: #"(":: xs`, and then check if `xs` ends with a `#")"` using [`List.last`](http://mosml.org/mosmllib/List.html#last-val).
- If you need it to be faster than the approach above, you probably would need to use a specialized data structure that allows for faster reading from both ends of a list. This could for instance a double-ended queue. [Okasaki](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf) has details on these.